# JPA/Hibernate for DDL

Tags: java, database, frameworks, ddl

Any Java library/framework that is equivalent to JPA/Hibernate (which is more DML) but at DDL level, for example CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE for different RDBMS database vendors (MySQL, PostgresQL, Oracle etc) that

1. Generate DDL script dynamically at runtime.
2. String free coding, like jOOQ or QueryDSL.
3. Handle differences of databases as listed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/217230/418439.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for something like:

- http://flywaydb.org/
- http://www.liquibase.org/

The first one has a Java API, so you might prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

Author of JOOQ library recommends Liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org/) for portable DDL abstraction over different databases:
http://blog.jooq.org/2011/10/24/liquibase-for-db-migrations/

Regarding point 3), Liquibase also supports generic datatypes:

"To help make scripts database-independent, the following “generic” data types will be converted to the correct database implementation: * BOOLEAN * CURRENCY * UUID * CLOB * BLOB * DATE * DATETIME * TIME * BIGINT

Also, specifying a java.sql.Types.* type will be converted to the correct type as well. If needed, precision can be included. Here are some examples: * java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP * java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(255)"

source: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html

Comment: Note: We (at [Data Geekery](http://www.datageekery.com), the company behind [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)) don't have a preference with respect to comparing Liquibase and Flywaydb...